# How in custom package data checking with making plugin unavailable in case of error?

Tags: laravel

Making custom package with custom data kept in migration/seeder files  on laravel 9 site and reading docs https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/packages
I did not find in which way I can run some data checking on plugin installation ?

In file packages/companyname/Mypackage/src/Providers/MypackageProvider.php

I have loaded migration files :

```
$this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/../database/migrations');
```

I have a custom class, running which I got list of errors in case of data in related tables have logical errors.
I think to make functionality to run this checking process from dashboard of my site

Also I would like in case of such errors to show some errors when I run this checking process manually and maybe (if that is possible)
when I run commands in console of the site :

```
composer install mypackage
composer dump-autoload
```

and migrating migration/seeder files of this plugin...

Also is cases of  logical errors I would like in the app make a condition like :

```
if(class_exists(mypackage::class)) {
```

and make functionality of this plugin unavailable...
How that can be implemented ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^9.41"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want to do is check some conditions on the user app before your package may be used, but I think you can check these conditions before the user install the package, executing an script before installing the package using a composer script [**pre-install-cmd**](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md). After installing your package  you can use the [**boot**](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/providers#the-boot-method) method of your service provider and execute all those conditions that have to be meet before using the functionality and abort if they are not presents.

Hope this help.